# How can i add an automatic View from controller using ASP.NET Core with VS RC 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I start using ASP.net Core and i didnt find a way to generate an automatic view from my controller.
Like in MVC 4 , just need to right click -->Add View (or Go to View) but i dnt find them with asp.net core.

Comment: This feature does not yet exist as it did with `ASP.NET Proper` tooling. With `ASP.NET Core` you have to do this by hand, which really isn't that big of an inconvience.

Comment: I add a package with Nuget console : Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Pre,its'nt make the view gerneration automatic but its helpful for binding them with model

Answer (score 1):

Tooling is still in preview, and not complete for ASP.NET Core in VS.

The tooling will be RTM with the release of VS2017 RTM.

You can simply create a new view manually, only difference is that you will have to manually add the model type etc and make sure you create the view following the naming conventions for MVC.